# Ubuntu 16.04 Can't adjust screen brightness Nvidia 750M

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, lenovo, screen, brightness

I recently tried to install f.lux on my laptop and it didn't work, so I uninstalled it and tried to install redshift, which also didn't work. I uninstalled redshift and tried to adjust my screen brightness and it wouldn't work. I had to install Brightness-Controller in order to adjust my screen brightness, but would prefer to use the keys to adjust the screen brightness for convenience. Any ideas of what the problem is?

Comment: Do you have the proprietary NVIDIA drivers installed?

Comment: I'm using the nivida binary driver version 367.57